# How to verify contracts that were deployed through Remix using Chainlink Imports?

Tags: ethereum, verify, chainlink, etherscan

Advice for **verifying** contracts that were deployed through Remix using Chainlink Imports?  Currently BSCScan (and I believe Etherscan) have the [following limitation](https://docs.bscscan.com/api-endpoints/contracts#verify-source-code):

> Contracts that use "imports" will need to have the code concatenated
> into one file as we do not support "imports" in separate files.

The issue is that VRFConsumerBase.sol has additional imports in it as well.  Making the concatenation process a bit burdensome.  [I've done this following @Patrick Collins's video with Hardhat](https://youtu.be/9oERTH9Bkw0?t=4400) pretty easily but the project I'm working with is developed in Remix.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's working as designed unfortunately. Unless etherscan/bsscan etc changes their processes, you either have to do alot of manual appending of code.

As an alternative, you can take all the code from remix and throw into a new [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) project, and then use the [hardhat-etherscan](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html) plugin to easily verify the contracts